# Creating Python function with partial parameters

Tags: python, lambda

I want to pass a Python function to another function with some of its parameters "filled out" ahead of time.

This is simplification what I am doing:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def increment_factory(i):  # create a function that increments by i
    return (lambda y: add(i, y))

inc2 = increment_factory(2)

print inc2(3) # prints 5
```

I don't want to use some sort of passing of `args` and later exploding it with `*args` because the function I am passing `inc2` into doesn't know to pass `args` to it.

This feels a bit too clever for a group project... is there a more straightforward or pythonic way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is called currying, or partial application. You can use the built-in [functools.partial()](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Something like the following would do what you want.

```
import functools
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

inc2 = functools.partial(add, 2)
print inc2(3)
```

Comment: Thanks!  One of my favorite features of Haskell is the built-in currying. I should have just used the term :).

Answer (score 2):

You could also accomplish the same with a `lambda` function:

```
inc2 = lambda y: add(2, y)

print inc2(3)
```

Comment: This is a way better answer. Accomplishes currying with simpler code and no import.