# how to pass a parameter to function without calling it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a two-variables function like

```py
def f(x1, x2):
    return x1 + x2
```

Now, I want to pass a series of `x2` into function `f` without calling it, to create a series of new functions. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by `pass a series of x2`

Comment: What do you mean ‘pass into a function without calling it’?  Sounds a bit like ‘how do I go swimming, without getting into the water’.  Please clarify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does functools partial do what it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does)

Comment: Why closed? The phrase: `"create a series of new functions"` seems clear to me. There is even an answer here on that basis.

Comment: @quamrana existing close reason isn't good, but it's a dupe of [Creating Python function with partial parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258756)

Comment: @SuperStormer: Ok, I'll make a note of that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this sounds like a job for `functools.partial`:

```py
def f(x1, x2):
    return x1 + x2

from functools import partial
funcs = [partial(f, x2=i) for i in range(10)]  # example use case
```